# How to check neighbours of 2D array board game

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I have to create a 2-dimensional board game. I've managed to do the board and I'm able to set the 'X' row and col coordinated show.
The last this what I need to do, is check the surroundings of an 'X' whether given coordinates land on this neighbourhood area or not. This should cover `isIsolated()` method.

I have two cases:

1. When 'X' is somewhere in the middle of the board:

- If coordinates land on **(bold) 0** area, my method should `return false`, if somewhere else as not in the neighbourhood, then `return true`
- for example, setting my point on `(3, 3)`, checking if point `(2, 1)` `isIsolated()` and it should return `true`, because it isn't close to or in the area of `X`, for point `(2, 3)`, it returns `false`, because it lands on the area

0 0 0 0 0 0

0 **0 0 0** 0 0

0 **0** X **0** 0 0

0 **0 0 0** 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0

2. And when 'X' is in the corners:

- The same thing here, if given coordinates land on **(bold) 0** area, my method should `return false`, otherwise `return true`
- for example, I set my points on `(1, 1)` and `(3, 4)`, so if I want to check if point `(2, 2)` `isIsolated()`, I should get `false`, if f.g point`(1, 3)`, it should return `true`

X **0** 0 0

**0 0 0 0**

0 0 **0** X

My code looks like this so far:

```
public class Board {
    public char[][] field;

    public Board(int rows, int columns) {
        field = new char[rows][columns];
        for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++){
                field[row][col] = '0';
            }
        }

    }

    public void set(int row, int column) {
        try{
            for (int r = 0; r < field[0].length ; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < field[1].length ; c++){
                    if(r == row - 1 && c == column - 1 && field[r][c] != 'X'){
                        field[r][c] = 'X';
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            if(row > field[0].length || column > field[1].length){
                System.out.println("Board isn't big enough!");
            }
        }


        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(field));
    }

    public boolean isSet(int row, int column) {
        for(int r = 0; r < field[0].length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < field[1].length; c++){
                if(r == row - 1 && c == column - 1){
                    if(field[r][c] == 'X'){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isIsolated(int row, int column) {
  
        return true;
    }

}
```

And tests for it:

```
    @Test
    public void boardKnowsIfSquareIsIsolated() {

        Board board = new Board(5, 6);

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(3, 3), is(true));

        board.set(3, 3);

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(2, 2), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(2, 3), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(2, 4), is(false));

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(3, 2), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(3, 3), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(3, 4), is(false));

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(4, 2), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(4, 3), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(4, 4), is(false));

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(4, 5), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void canHandleEdges() {

        Board board = new Board(3, 4);

        board.set(1, 1);
        board.set(3, 4);

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(1, 1), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(1, 2), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(3, 3), is(false));
        assertThat(board.isIsolated(3, 4), is(false));

        assertThat(board.isIsolated(1, 4), is(true));
    }
```

Comment: `field` is a `char[][]`, so `cell()` method should return a `char`, and should return `-` (or something else) when outside the board. The calls to `cell()` from `isIsolated()` should compare to `'0'`, not `0`.

Comment: *FYI:* Methods `set()` and `isSet()` shouldn't have `for` loops. They can access `field[row - 1][column - 1]` directly.

Comment: You show the board using `X` (letter ex), `O` (letter oh), and `-` (dash), but your code fills the board with `0` (digit zero), and there is no code for setting a `-` (dash), so it's impossible for that code to create those boards. You should fix these discrepancies. Not for us, but for yourself.

Comment: @Andreas no no, '-' means like neighbourhhood area which I should check, on my actual bord there are only 0's, and x is placed when I need to set the coordinate there

Comment: @Andreas I changed my examples, maybe it is now better to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 0-based `r,c` coordinate and want to check if it is an `'X'` or is near an `'X'`, you really want to check the 3-by-3 square around the `r,c` coordinate, i.e. the square with upper-left at `r-1,c-1` and lower-right at `r+1,c+1`. You can use loops for that.

```java
private static boolean isNearX(int r, int c) {
    for (y = r - 1; y <= r + 1; y++)
        for (x = c - 1; x <= c + 1; x++)
            if (field[y][x] == 'X')
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Of course, that 3-by-3 square may fall partially outside the board, so we need to check the upper and lower limits of the loops. This more efficient than checking the coordinates for every cell in the 3-by-3 square.

```java
private static boolean isNearX(int r, int c) {
    int minY = Math.max(r - 1, 0), maxY = Math.min(r + 1, field.length - 1);
    int minX = Math.max(c - 1, 0), maxX = Math.min(c + 1, field[0].length - 1);
    for (y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
        for (x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
            if (field[y][x] == 'X')
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Now, if you want to call it with the 1-based `row,column` coordinate instead, that's easy to adjust. We can also flip the true/false value to make it match the `isIsolated` point of view instead.

```java
public static boolean isIsolated(int row, int column) {
    int minY = Math.max(row - 2, 0), maxY = Math.min(row, field.length - 1);
    int minX = Math.max(column - 2, 0), maxX = Math.min(column, field[0].length - 1);
    for (y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
        for (x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
            if (field[y][x] == 'X')
                return false;
    return true;
}
```